# Argument deduction fail while passing lambda as parameter

Tags: c++, function, lambda

I have my function;

```
template < typename T > 
inline 
vector<T> listIntersection (  vector<T>& v1, vector<T>& v2, function<bool(T, T)> comprarer )
```

When I am calling this function like:

```
v_intersection = listIntersection( v1, v2, []( A left, A right )
{
    return left.getNumber() < right.getNumber();
});
```

Argument deduction is failing. 
But instead if I use `<A>` as below;

```
v_intersection = listIntersection<A>( v1, v2, []( A left, A right )
{
    return left.getNumber() < right.getNumber();
});
```

Program compiles. Why template argument deduction is failing in first case?

Not necessary but full example can be seen below;

```
struct A 
{
    int a;
    A ( int in )
    {
        a = in;
    }
    int getNumber( )
    {
        return a ;
    }; 
};


template < typename T > 
inline 
vector<T> listIntersection (  vector<T>& v1, vector<T>& v2, function<bool(T, T)> comprarer )
{
    std::sort(v1.begin(), v1.end(), comprarer);
    std::sort(v2.begin(), v2.end(), comprarer);

    vector<T> v_intersection;

    std::set_intersection(v1.begin(), v1.end(),
                          v2.begin(), v2.end(),
                          std::back_inserter(v_intersection), comprarer);

    return v_intersection;
}




int main()
{
    std::vector<A> v1{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
    std::vector<A> v2{    11, 13, 5,  7,  9,10};

    std::vector<A> v_intersection;
    v_intersection = listIntersection<A>( v1, v2, []( A left, A right )
    {
        return left.getNumber() < right.getNumber();
    });

    for(auto n : v_intersection)
        std::cout << n.getNumber() << ' ';
}
```

Comment: A lambda is not the same as a `std::function`, even though you can initialize a `std::function` with a lambda. If you use a template parameter for the `comprarer` function it should work, otherwise just wrap your lambda in a `std::function` explicitly.

Comment: You could have reduced your test case to just `template <typename T> f(function<void(T)>) {}` and then trigger the error with `int main() { f([](int){}); }`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A closure object is not a `std::function`, it has some unnamed type. The compiler can't do the implicit conversion to a `std::function` with unknown template arguments in one step.

If don't want to pass in the template argument explicitly, you could just make the function parameter a template parameter type rather than committing to `std::function`:

```
template < typename T, typename Fn > 
inline 
vector<T> listIntersection (  vector<T>& v1, vector<T>& v2, Fn comprarer )
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: Having `std::function` parameters is probably a bad idea in general unless you're using virtual functions.

Comment: @Simple What should I use instead of std::function in this case

Comment: @KadirErdemDemir You should use what's in the answer.